# Field name to string in Delphi XE10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Is there some way to get the name of a field as a string? For example, if I have a class

```
type
 TMyClass = Class
  private 
    fMyField:string
  published
    procedure SomeProcedure
end;
```

And in the procedure `SomeProcedure` I would like to access the name of the field `fMyField`, something alomg the lines of

```
procedure TMyClass.SomeProcedure;
var
sFieldName:string;
begin
  sFieldName := fMyField.FieldName;
  ShowMessage(sFieldName)
end;
```

Where the `ShowMessage(sFieldName)` would display "fMyField". Is this possible?

Comment: Use enhanced RTTI

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan! I'll be able to find a solution now, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to use [Run-time type information(RTTI)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index) in this case. `TRTTIContext` has a function [`GetFields()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetFields) that returns all information about fields

```
uses System.Rtti;

procedure TMyClass.SomeProcedure;
var 
  LRttiContext: TRTTIContext;
  LRttiType: TRttiType;
  LRttiField: TRttiField;
begin
  LRttiType := LRttiContext.GetType(TMyClass);
  for LRttiField in LRttiType.GetFields do
  begin
    if LRttiField.Parent = LRttiType  then    
      ShowMessage(LRttiField.Name);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TRTTIContext` is a record, no need to free.

Comment: No need to create it either, that is done automatically

Comment: Now, how are you going to identify `fMyField`? You'll need to look at its offset.

Comment: Thank you @MegaTron, that was very instructive! I have not used RTTI before and I think I will be able to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: `TRTTIContext` exposes the `Free` procedure which sets its `FContextToken: IInterface` field to `nil` but obviously its *infamous* name leads to confusion

Comment: @fantaghirocco, to add to the confusion, a `TRTTIContext` variable is best declared global.

Comment: @LURD in that case it's better you don't use `Free` because the cached object are reused.. `Inc(confusion)` :D